# Can't create new Android Project

Tags: android, project

I am tyring to start a new Android Project inside Eclipse. When creating the folder I get the following message:

My_Project_Name overlaps the location of another project: 'My_Project_Name'

I am not seeing anything wrong with it and the project name is new, so should not already exist.

Anyone seeing the same issue?

-- Eric

Answer (score 3):

A folder with the same name which is not in your workspace (not in your package explorer in eclipse) may also produce this error. If so, check your workspace directory and delete that folder.

Answer (score 1):

- use default Workspace folder

this happened to me when i tried to create new project outside the workspace, really i dont know whats that for.